# How is "n+n/2+n/4....1" equal to "2n-1" using the formula for geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, asymptotics

I never knew not having good knowledge of basic maths will be so crippling!! So please help me out this time. I'll be working on my maths from today on.

I was discussing about complexity of an algorithm on StackOverflow and I was told that the series $n+n/2+n/4 + \dots + 1$ evaluates to $2n-1$ and I was linked to the following formula on Wikipedia:

[image: Geometric series formula]

Even after trying hard, I regret to say I still don't get it how using this formula I can conclude that my series evaluates to $2n-1$. Please help me out as I am sure it will take only a few seconds for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748454/complexity-for-nested-loops-diving-by-2?noredirect=1#comment24124682_16748454

Comment: First question on maths.stackexchange.com.Hence bear with me this time.

Comment: Your expression makes no sense (what is " ...1"?). Is this the infinite sum: $n+n/2+n/4+\cdots$? If so, it evaluates to $2n$, not $2n-1$. ($a+ar+ar^2+\cdots={1\over 1-r}$ for $|r|<1$. Here, you have $a=n$ and $r=1/2$.)

Comment: @DavidMitra Edited it now.Actually I copy-pasted it from that site,what that original user said.

Comment: @DavidMitra How did you get `(a+ar+ar^2+⋯=1/(1−r) for |r|<1.`

Comment: While we are at it,where to learn formatting for mathematical code for math.stackexchange? What should I do to raise `a` to power `r` instead of `a^r`?

Comment: @DavidMitra Your full-fledged answer will help a lot.How do I proceed from `a(1-(1/2)^a)/(1-1/2)`  to get `2n` when **n** is a multiple of 2?

Comment: Ok, so in your expression, $n=2^m$ for some $m$? Let's just use $2^m$, here; there is another "$n$" in the wiki formula that is different from the "$n$" in your expression. Your expression is then $2^m(\color{maroon}{1+{1\over2}+{1\over 2^2}+\cdots+{1\over 2^m}})$.  To evaluate the $\color{maroon}{\text{parenthetical expression}}$, use the wiki formula with $a=1$, $r=1/2$, and $n=m+1$. It gives the value, after some arithmetic,  $2-{1\over 2^m}$.  So the original expression evaluates to $2^m(2-{1\over 2^m})=2\cdot2^{m}-1$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I started the evaluation of the right-side expression,based on your first comment,as $n(1-(1/2)^n)/(1-1/2)=2n(1-1/2^n)=2n-2n/2^n$ and then I got lost after this.Where did I go wrong?After all I begun with the premise you provided,ie, `a=n` and `r=1/2`?

Comment: @DavidMitra I just learnt it!!That enclosing mathematical lines within the dollar symbol converts it into formatted mathematical lines!!

Comment: Please ignore the first comment. You do not have the infinite series I assumed there. Rather, use the method in my second comment. Note that you have to use $a=2^m$ (*your* $n$) and for the "$n$" in the wiki formula, use $n=m+1$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thansk for pointing it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, in the linked StackOverflow question, the program does integer division at each step, so "n/2" in that context actually means the greatest integer less than or equal to $\frac{n}{2}$: more correctly, it should be written as $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$ (where $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor$ is the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), e.g. $\left\lfloor \frac{7}{2} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor 3.5 \right\rfloor = 3$).

Secondly, you missed a clause mentioned at the linked StackOverflow question: the correct statement is that **if $n$ is a power of $2$,** then $\left\lfloor n \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \right\rfloor + \dots$ (which in this case is the same as $n + \frac{n}2 + \frac{n}4 + \dots + 1$) is exactly $2n - 1$.

For this special case when $n$ is a power of $2$ (which is what it takes for all the numbers $\frac{n}2, \frac{n}4, \dots$ to be integers, all the way to $1$), this is easy to prove. When $n$ is a power of $2$, say $n = 2^k$, the sum is 
$$2^k + \frac{2^k}{2} + \frac{2^k}{4} + \dots + 1 
= 2^k + 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-2} + \dots + 1
= 2^{k+1} - 1
= 2n - 1
$$
For example, $16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 31$.

This can be proved by induction, or it follows from the formula for the geometric series, which states that $$a + ar + ar^2 + \dots + ar^{m-1} = a\frac{1-r^m}{1-r}.$$

In this case, we have $a = n = 2^k$, $r = 1/2$, and $m$ (the number of terms) is $k+1$, so the left-hand side is the sum $n + \frac{n}{2} + \dots + 1$, and the right-hand side is $$n \frac{1 - (1/2)^{k+1}}{1 - (1/2)} = n\frac{2 - (1/2)^k}{1} = 2n - n/2^k = 2n - 1.$$

---

But more generally, when $n$ need not be a power of $2$, still we can upper-bound the sum by $n + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{4} + \dots$ (all the way to infinitely many terms). The formula for the infinite geometric series (when $|r| < 1$) is 
$$a + ar + ar^2 + \dots = a\frac{1}{1-r}.$$
Here with $a = n$ and $r = 1/2$, we have $$n + \frac{n}{2} + \dots = n\frac{1}{1-1/2} = 2n.$$ 
As our finite sum is an integer strictly less than this upper bound, we can say it's at most $2n - 1$.

Comment: The lower bound is $2n-1-\lfloor\lg n\rfloor$. Proof: Let $k=1+\lfloor\lg n\rfloor$ so that $2^{k-1}\le n<2^k$. Note that $\lfloor x\rfloor\ge x-1$, so we have $n + \left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}4\right\rfloor + \dots \ge n + \frac{n}2 + \dots + \frac{n}{2^{k-1}} - (k-1) = n\frac{1-(1/2)^k}{1-(1/2)} - k+1 = 2n-\frac{2n}{2^k}-k+1$, so the LHS (as it's an integer) is $\ge 2n - k$. This is achieved when $n = 2^k - 1$: we have $n + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor + \dots = (2^k - 1) + (2^{k-1} - 1) + \dots + (2^1 - 1) = 2^{k+1} - k - 2 = 2n - k$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n= 2^p$ where $p = 1, 2, 3, ...$

$2n = n + n$

$2n  = n + n/2 + n/4 + n/4$

Similarly, it can be expanded as

$2n = n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + .....+ n/2^p  + n/2^p$

$2n = n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16 + ......+ 1 + 1$ where ($n = 2^p$)

$n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16 + ......+ 1  = 2n - 1$

Comment: What if $n$ is **not** of the form $2^p$?

Comment: Then, 2n - 1 is not equal to the series “n+n/2+n/4…1”.

Answer (score 1):

The formula provided on the wikipedia page works if you know how many terms you are adding. For example, if you want to calculate the sum $1 + \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \dots \frac{1}{2^9}$, you know you are adding 10 terms (so $n = 10$). Also, $a = 1$ (the number you begin with) and $r = \frac{1}{2}$ (the common ratio). Now you could use the provided formula to calculate the sum:

\begin{align*}
a \frac{1-r^n}{1-r} &= 1 \frac{1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2^{10}}}{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= 2(1 - \frac{1}{2^{10}})\\
&= 2 - \frac{2}{2^{10}}\\
&= 2 - \frac{1}{2^9}
\end{align*}

You are talking abouth the sum $a + \frac{a}{2} + \frac{a}{4} + \dots + 1$, so the last term is 1, instead of $ar^{n-1}$. Note that $r = \frac{1}{2}$ in your case, as each term is twice as small as the term before. The formula could still solve this problem, but you will have to set $a\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$ equal to 1:

\begin{align*}
a\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1} &= 1\\
a &= \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} = 2^{n-1}
\end{align*}

So, your formula will only work when $a$ is a power of two. For example, if $a = 4$:

$$
4 + 2 + 1 = 7 = 8 - 1 = 2*4 - 1
$$

So for $a=4$, your formula works. Let's try $a = 16$:

$$
16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 31 = 32 - 1 = 2 * 16 - 1
$$

Again, your formula works. How would we prove this? The formula you found on wikipedia has a $r^n$ term that we would like to get rid of:

\begin{align*}
a\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1} &= 1\\
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1} &= \frac{1}{a}\\
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n &= \frac{1}{a} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2a}
\end{align*}

So, $r = \frac{1}{2}$ and $r^n = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n = \frac{1}{2a}$. Now, let's plug that in:

\begin{align*}
a \frac{1-r^n}{1-r} &= a \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2a}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}}\\
&= a \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2a}}{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= 2a(1 - \frac{1}{2a})\\
&= 2a - \frac{2a}{2a}\\
&= 2a - 1
\end{align*}

So there you have it: for every $a = 2^k$ (with $k \in \mathbb{N}$):

$$
a + \frac{a}{2} + \frac{a}{4} + \dots + 1 = 2a - 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $n$ is a power of $2$, say $n = 2^p$. Then the sum is
$$
S = n + \frac n2 + \frac n4 + \ldots + 1 =
2^p + 2^{p-1} + 2^{p-2} + \ldots + 1.
$$
Multiply by $2$ on both sides to get
$$
2S_p = 2^{p+1} + 2^p + 2^{p-1} + \ldots + 2.
$$
Compute the difference $2S_p - S_p$ using the two equations above:
\begin{align*}
2S_p - S_p & = 2^{p+1} - 1 \\
\therefore S_p & = 2^{p+1} - 1 = 2n - 1.
\end{align*}

---

For a discussion of the general series, suppose $a \ne 1$ and $p \in \mathbb N$ are given, and suppose we want to compute
$$
S = 1 + a + a^2 + \ldots + a^p = \sum_{i=0}^p a^i.
$$
We can use the same idea as above: multiply by $a$ to get
$$
aS = a + a^2 + a^3 + \ldots + a^{p+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{p+1} a^i.
$$
Compute the difference:
\begin{align*}
aS - S & = a^{p+1} - 1 \\
(a - 1)S & = a^{p+1} - 1\\
S & = \frac{a^{p+1} - 1}{a - 1}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

If you have knowledge of progression than this is a geometric series with common ratio of $\frac{1}{2}$ and formula you have written is sum to n terms of geometric progression.

But you  require to calculate the sum of this series upto $2n-1$ term, so you can replace $n$ with $(2n-1)$ and then proceed. Here , $a = n$ (which is your first term).

So, by putting these values we get : $\frac{a(1-r^{2n-1})}{1-r}$ =

$\frac{n(1-(\frac{1}{2})^{2n-1})}{1-\frac{1}{2}}$

I hope from here you  will get your answer....

Comment: But **davidmitra** says n=a here,so why can't we use 1-r^a instead to begin with?

Comment: So according to **david** we should begin a `a(1-r^a)/(1-r)` where r is 1/2.

Comment: Someone downvoted you and it has added to my confusion.

Comment: @sultan I think you need to be careful which $n$ is which. You are using $n$ as both the first term of the sequence, as well as the number of terms in your partial sum in your last line.

Comment: My apology I didn't see the series approaches to 1.....